# question about auto in c++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any reason to use the ‘auto’ keyword in C / C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046477/is-there-any-reason-to-use-the-auto-keyword-in-c-c)

can anybody explain me  purpose of auto keyword in c++? thanks

Comment: Can you consider buying a book on C++? And how about learning to search SO?

Comment: google 'auto keyword c++', first hit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k3ybftz(VS.80).aspx, which says it's redundant and means the same as stating no storage class as all (which you usually don't)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192547/where-is-the-c-auto-keyword-used

Comment: The above mentioned question convers the usage of 'auto' in C. Question is about C/C++. The meaning of 'auto' in C++ recently changed with the upcoming c++0x standard, which indeed gives 'auto' a new, very respectable and useful role. UPDATE: The "Possible Duplicate" Question mentions the new usage of auto.

Answer (score 0):

It's useless and is left for old code compatibility. Long ago you used it to say that a variable is automatic, this is no longer useful - all variables witout other qualifiers are treated as automatic (stack-allocated).

Comment: Actually, as of C++0x, auto has been moved back into the spotlight. It's now used for automatic type inference, quite like var in C#. E.g. auto it = myvec.begin();