# having trouble with vector.erase() and remove_if()

Tags: c++, vector, erase-remove-idiom

Prior to using remove_if, I was using remove. So say if I had vec = {1, 2, 2, 2, 5}, and wanted to remove all 2s, I would do:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it!= vector.end(); ++it){
    if (*it == 2){
       vec.erase(remove(vec.begin(),vec.end(), *it), vec.end());
    }
}
```

This will not work as it's not possible and illogical to iterate through a vector as deletion is being done.

So then I discovered remove_if(). However, for some reason I can't get it to work within the context of a class. Here's my code:

```
class SomeClass{
    private:
       vector<int> vec;
    public:
       SomeClass(){
           //initalizae vec to {1,2,2,2,4,5,6,8}
       }
       bool is_even(int value){
           return value % 2 == 0;
       }
       void delete(int a){
           vec.erase(remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), a), vec.end());
       }
       void delete_even(int a){
           vec.erase(remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), this->is_even(a)), vec.end());
       }
```

I am guessing void delete will not work because a is an int and I need a bool value, but not sure how to express "if int a is in this vector return true" as the third parameter for remove_if. And I'd expect void delete_even to work but I get

```
note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::remove_if<std::__1::__wrap_iter<int *>, bool>' requested here
```

Comment: `void delete(int a)` is insane

Comment: Why are you erasing the return of `remove_if` ??

Comment: @YSC Because that's how it works with iterators and `remove`. Confusing, but true.

Comment: @MicroVirus That's true, my bad. End of the week here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `std::remove` to remove an `int` value from the collection, without searching for it yourself:

```
vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 2), vec.end());
```

This will remove all occurrences of `2` from `vec`.

The usage of `remove_if` is the same, only then rather than an element you give a predicate (typically a function); if C++11 is available to you, you can use it with a lambda as such:

```
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int a) {return a % 2 == 0;}), vec.end());
```

If you want to use `is_even` as a predicate to `remove_if` (or another member function of your class), then as mentioned in the comments, you should make it a static member function, preferably.
You can also `bind` to non-static members, but there's no real reason to do that here; but see [Using std::bind with member function, use object pointer or not for this argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264003/using-stdbind-with-member-function-use-object-pointer-or-not-for-this-argumen) if you're curious, the question itself contains the correct syntax.
A sample for `is_even` as static:

```
 static bool is_even(int value) {
     return value % 2 == 0;
 }

 void delete_even(int a){
     vec.erase(remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), is_even), vec.end());
 }
```

Comment: Could you explain what a predicate is, is that related to the error that I posted? and will remove also work in the delete_even method?

Comment: A predicate is just a fancy word for a 'function' that can return either `true` or `false`, based on its input. For instance, your `is_even` is a predicate.

Comment: I think the issue is that you can't use a member function for a predicate.  Unless it's the member function operator().

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove some value from the vector than you can just use `remove()`

```
foo.erase(std::remove(foo.begin(), foo.end(), some_value), foo.end());
```

If you want to remove all even numbers then instead of using a class member function I would suggest using a lambda.

```
foo.erase(std::remove_if(foo.begin(), foo.end(), [](auto n) { return n % 2 == 0;}), foo.end());
```

Here is an example using both approaches

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> foo = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    // remove all even numbers
    foo.erase(std::remove_if(foo.begin(), foo.end(), [](auto n) { return n % 2 == 0;}), foo.end());
    for (auto e : foo)
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    // remove all elemenets that match some_value
    foo = {1,2,2,2,2,2,7,8,9};
    int some_value = 2;
    foo.erase(std::remove(foo.begin(), foo.end(), some_value), foo.end());
    for (auto e : foo)
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1
3
5
7
9

1
7
8
9
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e223b30ca900fca0)</kbd>

Comment: what is the auto for? don't variables default to auto?

Comment: @jasonadams [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) is a specifier that tells the compiler to deduce the correct type for the variable.  What do you mean by *don't variables default to auto?*

Comment: I didn't know what auto was used for so I went to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046477/is-there-any-reason-to-use-the-auto-keyword-in-c03

Comment: @jasonadams Ah.  Auto in C++11 and above is different.  see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto